# Dynamically add layouts to a Linearlayout having some ID issues

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a LinearLayout inside ScrollView(Root)
There is another Linearlayout(id = consultingTimeContainer) which is inside the root Linear layout.
I have inflated a layout and added this inflated layout to Linear Layout(consultingTimeContainer). The inflation works correctly. But the problem is when i set text in 3rd inflated layout, the text changes in the first inflated layout.

There is a function showTimePicker(viewId: Int). The function show a time picker and set the picked time to the EditText having id = viewId.

Everytime i try to set time in inflated view which is not first inflated view, the time is set in the firstly inflated view!

```
fun addNewConsultingTime(firstOne: Boolean) {
        val inflatedView: View? =
            LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_consulting_time, null)
        consultingTimeContainer.addView(inflatedView, consultingTimeContainer.childCount)
        val addNewConsultingTime = inflatedView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.add)
        val consultingFrom = inflatedView?.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.consultingFrom)
        val consultingTo = inflatedView?.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.consultingTo)
        consultingFrom?.isFocusable = false
        consultingFrom?.isClickable = true
        consultingTo?.isClickable = true
        consultingTo?.isFocusable = false

        if (firstOne) {
            addNewConsultingTime?.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus_icon)
            addNewConsultingTime?.tag = "add"
        } else {
            addNewConsultingTime?.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove)
            addNewConsultingTime?.tag = "remove"
        }
        addNewConsultingTime?.setOnClickListener {
            if (addNewConsultingTime.tag == "add")
                addNewConsultingTime(false)
            else
                consultingTimeContainer.removeView(addNewConsultingTime.parent as View)
        }
        consultingTo?.setOnClickListener {
            showTimePicker(consultingTo.id)
        }
        consultingFrom?.setOnClickListener {
            showTimePicker(consultingFrom.id)
        }
    }
```

```
fun showTimePicker(viewId: Int) {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
            findViewById<EditText>(viewId).setText(SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time))
        }
        TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show()
    }
```

When i set time as 02:00 in second inflated view, the time is actually displayed in firstly inflated edittext as 02:00. This is wrong.

I think that the every inflated layout has childs with same ids. How to overcome this issue ?

Comment: add logs please what happen there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said: "I think that the every inflated layout has childs with same ids. How to overcome this issue ?"
Did you check with logs or in debug mode that the id of views correspond to the good views?
Also, is it not possible to use layout in xml instead of inflate in code?

What I can suggest is not to send the id in parameter but the view

```
 consultingFrom?.setOnClickListener { v -> showTimePicker(v)}
```

and in showTimePicker

```
fun showTimePicker(edt: EditText) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        edt.setText(SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time))
    }
    TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show()
}
```

Comment: I need to get the values from the editText, How will i iterate through the views and fetch vales ?(Here elements hvae duplicate ids!!)

Comment: it's the same, don't use id but the view directly. Another solution could be to add tag to each view, and use this data instead of id